# How to send and receive multiple data from client to server

Tags: java, android

I have established a connection between java server and android client using sockets. I can send messages from android to java, but only 1 message at a time.
what if I want to send data of 2 variables from android to java and at the same time receive those data in java in 2 different variables.
How can I achieve this.??

Code for Android Client

```
public class MessageClient extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etMessage;
Button bSend;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messageclient);
    bSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    bSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.100",7000);
                DataOutputStream  dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(etMessage.getText().toString());
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

Code for java server

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
Thread t =  new Thread(){

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);

            while(true){

                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Server is running");
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("Received from client: "+dis.readUTF());

                dis.close();
                s.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   };
t.start();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why you are using socket connection.I will suggest you to make Rest based webservices at backend and do communication via it.It will make whole architecture easy and you can modify it as per your requirements.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understood, can you give some sites to learn from or any example you know.

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending a String and then closing the socket.You can try to send lists and also can send multiple  DataInputStream dis without closing the socket connection.

Comment: yeah you are right. I'll try to send multiple Streams of data. Thanks! :)